# using a string array as an element for a Vector in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, vector

i am interested in using a String array as an element in a Vector object. The array will always be of length 2. Is there a better way for this data structure? Reason for using the Vector is because of dynamic resizing, ie the number of elements vary and i would like to use the `add` and `trimToSize` methods for Vector.

Thanks!

Comment: Vector is deprecated.. You would better go with `ArrayList`.. Apart, can you show some code you might have tried??

Comment: Come to modern day. Use an `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: Use `ArrayList<Pair>` instead. `Pair` is a class you define which has 2 fields.

Comment: Or, even better, don't use `Pair` -- write a class that actually describes what the two strings actually mean.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes exactly :)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Agree that it's better to create a class with named elements, assuming that the values have distinct meanings, like "color" and "style" or whatever. If they're just #1 and #2, like space for two phone numbers or two friends' names or whatever, then I'd use an array rather than an object with fields called value1 and value2.

Comment: I think someone should point out that Vector is deprecated in favor of ArrayList.

Comment: @Jay.. See my first comment..

Comment: @RohitJain It's not deprecated, it's just no longer considered good practice to use due to the unnecessary overhead from the fact that it pretends to be thread safe with synchronized methods. It works, and it's not going to be removed in any future releases (the definition of deprecated is that it may be removed in the future), its use is just an indication of "immature code" (in the words of IDE hints).

Comment: @Brian.. Thanks for the info.. Earlier I though it was deprecated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ArrayList` and a custom object instead.

```
public class MyStrings {
    private String string1;
    private String string2;

    public MyStrings(String string1, String string2) {
        this.string1 = string1;
        this.string2 = string2;
    }

    public String getString1() {
        return string1;
    }

    public String getString2() {
        return string2;
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
List<MyStrings> list = new ArrayList<MyStrings>();
list.add(new MyString("apple", "orange");
// To iterate:
for (MyStrings myStrings : list) {
    System.out.println(myStrings.getString1());
    System.out.println(myStrings.getString2());
}
```

`Vector` is no longer considered a good dynamic array in Java because of extra synchronization logic that's more or less useless, so it just adds unnecessary overhead. `ArrayList` is the go-to dynamic array. You could also use `LinkedList`, which is a doubly-linked list.

Of course, you should also use better naming conventions that describe what the values actually mean instead of the names that I used in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Apache commons provides a nice [Pair class](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0-beta/org/apache/commons/lang3/Pair.html) to store two values. Using an array of size 2 would look a bit hacky.